# WSO2 API Manger Analytics : Does the analytics platform support third party APIs for monitoring?

Tags: api, wso2, analytics, monitoring, wso2-api-manager

Does WSO2 APIM Analytics allow to configure **third party APIs** for Monitoring and Analytics ?

Like, I've APIs developed in **spring-boot**. Is there any way to configure these APIs to WSO2 APIM Analytics server, so that I can do performance monitoring and analytics?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default WSO2 doesn't have support for this. But you will be able to get this done by customizing Stream Processor's events to support the third party APIs' OAuth App and API specific info.

Basically this is not supported OOTB and you have to customize WSO2's Analytics event streams, data bases, etc to get this done.

Comment: This is interesting. Do you have any document or any resource to which I can refer? It'll be very much helpful if you share it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a blog post regarding this, https://medium.com/api-integration-essentials/how-to-publish-custom-attributes-from-wso2-api-manager-to-wso2-analytics-38dd83e8aea2. But it is for the APIM versions where we used DAS for the Analytics. Since from APIM 2.6.0 onwards, we are using SP for Analytics, you need to do the required modifications matching to SP. Also please note that the DTOs are also different with DAS. You can refer this to have an idea to start with.